# c++ multithreading problems

Tags: c++, multithreading

So I've been trying to implement multithreading into my program (for macOS) but I've ran into a few problems, the first is when I try to exit the thread my main thread won't continue running, and my second problem is with every thread I create my cpu usage goes up by ~100% whats the best way for me lower my cpu usage?
Cheers

```c++
void *KeepListening(void *commandid) {

    long tid = (long)commandid;

    if(tid != 1)
        return 0;

    for(int i = 0; killthread == false ; i++) {

        if(i % WhenToSleep == 1)
            sleep(10);



        if(i % waittime == 1) {

            abc = con->post(listento, "request=abc");
            xyz = con->post(listento, "request=xyz");
            sleep(1);

            if(abc == "true") {
                threadscreated = false;
            } else if(abc == "false") {
                killthread = true;
            }
        }



    }

    cout << "Killing thread\n";
    shouldcreate = true;
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}


void Listen() {

    pthread_t threads[1];
    int rc;

    for(int i = 0;  ;i++) {

        if(i % WhenToSleep == 1)
            sleep(10);

        if(i % waittime == 1) {

            abc = con->post(listento, "request=abc");
            xyz = con->post(listento, "request=xyz");
            sleep(1);

            if(abc == "true") {
                threadscreated = false;
            } else if(abc == "false") {
                killthread = true;
            }

        }



        if(!threadscreated && shouldcreate) {

            rc = pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, HandleCommands, (void *)1);
            sleep(1);

            threadscreated  = true;
            shouldcreate    = false;

            cout << "Threads Created\n";

            sleep(5);

        }

    }


    pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but when you declare a function to return something the you *must* return something, or you will have *undefined behavior*. So in your thread function end it with returning `nullptr`. No need for the `pthread_exit` (which does the same thing as `return NULL` at that point).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude very good advice. Academic debate: since `pthread_exit` "does not return to the caller" I think technically it is not undefined behavior.

Comment: @bolov You're correct that calling `pthread_exit` will not lead to UB. But not returning in a function that's declared to return something, that's just... It just doesn't look right to me. :)

Comment: @pwned Why are you calling `pthread_exit` in the `Listen` function? Is it also a thread you have created? Or is it due to some copy-paste programming and you forgot to remove it? Because if it's in the main thread, then that will of course exit the main thread, leaving the (orphaned) sub-threads you have created.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I just forgot to remove it, but it doesnt get called anyways, and Listen is the main thread

Comment: What is the value of `WhenToSleep`? if it is ==1, then your threads would never sleep.

Comment: @K.Kirsz 1500000000

Comment: Well, that seems like the other extreme. If the thread sleeps every 1/1500000000 iterations, that means it is mostly incrementint the `i` value the rest of time. It can easily take up 100% of cpu imo. Did you try setting it lower? Like `5` or something?

Comment: C++ has std::thread.